# How to plot a multivalued function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

First of all, consider the cubic equation
$$x^3 + a = x. $$

Using Mathematica is easy to find real solutions of the above equation,

```
F[a_]:= Solve[x^3 + a == x , x, Reals]
```

Now, I would like to plot the graph of the multivalued  function $$G: [-1,1]\to 2^\mathbb{R}$$
$$a \mapsto\ \{\text{the real solutions of }x^3 + a =x\}, $$
 *i.e.* the set

$$\text{Graf}(G):= \{(x,y);\ x\in [-1,1]\ \text{and}\ y\in G(x)\}. $$

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ContourPlot[x^3 + a == x, {a, -1, 1}, {x, -2, 2}, FrameLabel -> {a, x}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, I forgot about ContourPlot. Thx!!!